# Custom resizeable div

Tags: html, css

After creating resizeable div (resize:both is CSS) i'm albe to resize it after clicking on right bottom corner of div. In firefox it looks like:
[image: item to change]

But i want to place there my custom image , how to do it ?

```
#resizeablediv {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    resize:both;
    background-color:black;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BSWxj/)

Comment: Please put your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: added, i want to change that small thing in right bottom corner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I did a little research on resize. It is so new not every major browsers even support it yet. From what I can tell there is not yet an existing method for restyling this element.

Here is the spec page for resize:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

So you have 2 options, neither of which is perfect:

1) Background image. Which won't hide the resize icon but will at least occlude it.

2) Overlay a div to contain your image with pointer-events: none; applied to it. The icon will still be there, but it can be hidden underneath an absolutely positioned div containing your image.

```
.custom-image{
    background:pink; //you could set this background to your custom image.
    height:7px;
    width:7px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle to demonstrate. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCV38/)

Answer (score 0):

here's how to get custom button / image - put whatever you want in the right bottom corner of div

```css
.parent {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:after {
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(14, 19, 24, .15);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  animation: blink 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5)
  }
  50% {
    background: transparent
  }
}

.child {
  background: salmon;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
  width: 345px;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
  resize: both;
  background: #444;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
  right: -7px;
  top: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  color: cyan;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #444;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="content">
    r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e r e s i z e a b l e
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
background: grey url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckblr.png) no-repeat bottom right;
```

Answer (score -1):

That is rendered by the browser, and those styles cant be changed with CSS.Please try placing your image (custom) on bottom-right.